# I am installing python 3 on snow leopard, what am I installing exactly?

Tags: python, python-3.x, osx-snow-leopard

I'm having difficulty installing python 3 on snow leopard.

I'm having difficulty because I have no idea what I am installing. (I do understand that python is a language, and that it uses a virtual machine)

Where can I get an overview of all the parts that make up working installation of python and how they need to be configured?

I want to understand this so that I can use python 3, but not break the other installations on my system.

Comment: Why do you need Python3?

Comment: Always include the error message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is normally no need to build Python on Mac OS X from source. If you want the most recent Python 3, download and install one of the two official Python 3.2 installers for OS X from python.org [here](http://www.python.org/download/releases/3.2/).  The Python installers from python.org install a framework build of Python 3 rooted at

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.2
```

In that directory, you will find `bin`, `lib`, and other directories unique to that version.  If you install another Python versions (say, 2.7) using python.org installers, it will be be installed under `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7`, completely independent of the `3.2` version.  There will also be a version of `IDLE.app` and other files installed into `/Applications/Python m.n` (3.2, 2.7, etc.).  The Apple-supplied system Pythons (2.6.1 and 2.5.4 for OS X 10.6) are installed in:

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/
```

again a completely separate location. Thus, the system Python files do not need to be and should not be altered or removed.  The python.org installers have the option to alter your shell `PATH` variable to prepend the appropriate framework `bin` directory to your path so that the newly installed Python will be found first.  With Python 3 there is no conflict anyway, since you need to invoke it by `python3`, rather than `python`.

The python.org installers also have the option to install symlinks from `/usr/local/bin` to the important files in the framework `bin` directory but, for various reasons, those are not particularly useful.  In general, you need to include the framework bin directory in your execution PATH; with that, the `/usr/local/bin` symlinks are usually not needed.

If you are really interested in the details, download the source tarball and examine `configure.in` and the top level makefile.  The script that is used to build the installer is in `Mac/BuildInstaller`.

For additional information about Python on Mac OS X and the use of Tkinter, IDLE, and Tcl/Tk, see [this page](http://www.python.org/download/mac/tcltk/).

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to Python.org
2. Download the source
3. Unpack
4. Follow the steps in the README (see below)

It will install to python3 by default thereby not breaking your other distros.

On Unix, Linux, BSD, OSX, and Cygwin:

```
./configure
make
make test
sudo make install
```

This will install Python as python3.

You can pass many options to the configure script; run "./configure --help" to
find out more.  On OSX and Cygwin, the executable is called python.exe;
elsewhere it's just python.

On Mac OS X, if you have configured Python with --enable-framework, you should
use "make frameworkinstall" to do the installation.  Note that this installs the
Python executable in a place that is not normally on your PATH, you may want to
set up a symlink in /usr/local/bin.

On Windows, see PCbuild/readme.txt.

If you wish, you can create a subdirectory and invoke configure from there.  For
example:

```
mkdir debug
cd debug
../configure --with-pydebug
make
make test
```

(This will fail if you *also* built at the top-level directory.  You should do a
"make clean" at the toplevel first.)

--

You are installing packages and modules. You can download the source and look through the directory. Everything installed is as it appears. This is not Windows where files are spewed everywhere on the system.